# how to use not equal operator in Cakephp

Tags: php

i am having a action in the cakephp controller as
     which takes the report_id as an argument and the Selected Fields as an array .

i am trying to compare the array that contains the already existing attribute ids with the array what i have received from the action post .. if that particular attribute id if not present in the received array then i am trying to delete that entry in the Report s table..
i am not aware of how to use the NOt equal to operator in this scenario . Help me please.......

```
function updateReport($report_id){
    $attribute_ids=$this->params['form']['attr'];
    $comma_separated = explode(",", $attribute_ids);
    $count=count($comma_separated);

    //$comma_separated contains 200,203
    $exists=$this->Report->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Report.report_id'=>$report_id)));
    //$exists contains the attributes as 200 , 201, 203

    foreach($exists as $exist){
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            if($exist['Report']['attribute_id']==$comma_separated[$i]){
                echo "not in array $comma_separated ".$exist['Report']['attribute_id'];echo "     ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [array_intersect()](http://php.net/array_intersect) and/or [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff).

```
$comma_separated = array(200, 203);
$exists=array(200, 201, 203);

foreach(array_diff($exists, $comma_separated) as $x) {
  echo $x, ' not in array $comma_separated. ';
}
```

prints

```
201 not in array $comma_separated.
```

Answer (score 0):

to look through an array to see if something is there, you need to do the following:

```
foreach($exists as $exist){
    $exists = false;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        if($exist['Report']['attribute_id']==$comma_separated[$i]){
            //It exists in the array;
            $exists = true;
        }
    }
    if($exists){
        echo "$exist['Report']['attribute_id'] exists";
    }else{
        echo "$exist['Report']['attribute_id'] does not exist";
    }
}
```